# Call being fired twice the second time the view being loaded and three time the third time without clearing the cache

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm having issue with this code and function `sendViewedUpdatesToAnalytics` being fired twice the second time I land on the view and three time when I land the third time without clearing the cache. Can someone help me?

```
initialize : function(){
    this.app.events.on('page:ready', this.onPageReady, this);
},
'onPageReady': function(){
    var sendViewedUpdatesToAnalytics = function(e){
        iCount++;
        viewportTop = $(document).scrollTop();
        e.preventDefault();
        if( updateOffset  >= viewportTop && updateOffset <= viewportTop + windowHeight ){
            console.log('hello world');
        }
    }
    window.addEventListener("scroll", sendViewedUpdatesToAnalytics, false); 
}
```

Comment: What library is it that has `this.app.events.on()`.

Comment: Without knowing the library I'd just guess removing/commenting out `iCount++` maybe fixes it as something gets incremented there.

Comment: my bad i added iCount++ by mistake and itshould not be there. and this.app.events.on() is the equivalent of .on() in jQuery for this custom library

Comment: If you really want to send this only once you should check if visiting the page with cleared cache sets a specific cookie. Then you could e.g. write a function to check if this cookie is set and only call this `sendViewedUpdatesToAnalytics` in case this cookie isn't there. But without knowing this app it's just guessing.